# in-house iPad app distribution - offline mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

We've built an app, which is suited to work offline after you install it and set-up with downloading some files from internet, then it goes to offline mode.

After a while (weeks), the App suddenly stop working, it crashes and the app screen turns into black. When we looked into profiles, the certificate is not there anymore. We have to delete the app and download it again so it works. Turning the wifi on didn't solve the issue.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you distributed the app as an Enterprise app? If so, the device needs to be able to periodically contact Apple's servers to validate the certificate or it will stop working. A custom app under a regular corporate program membership is probably better since it is signed by Apple and therefore never expires.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, yes I distributed with Xcode as Enterprise. Could you please elaborate on the other option so we don't face this issue? Thanks!

Comment: This [WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/304) covers it, but basically you create an app and upload it to App Store connect as if you were going to distribute it via the App Store but you only make it available to,your own organisation. You can then "purchase" this app via Apple Business Manager and distribute it to your devices using an MDM or Apple Configurator.